# ошибка "render is a Node specific API." при использовании модуля '@react-pdf/renderer'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf, react-native

использую библиотеку '@react-pdf/renderer' чтобы сохранить данные в pdf

при использовании код от разработчика (https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/@react-pdf/renderer):

```
    import ReactPDF, { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

    // Create styles
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        page: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
        },
        section: {
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        flexGrow: 1
        }
    });
    
    // Create Document Component
    const MyDocument = (): JSX.Element => (
        <Document>
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Section #1</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Section #2</Text>
                </View>
            </Page>
        </Document>
    );

    ReactPDF.render(<MyDocument />, 'd://example.pdf');
```

получаю ошибку

> Error: render is a Node specific API. You're either using this method
> in a browser, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf from the
> appropriate web build.

Подскажите пожалуйста с чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я могу видеть (и из ошибки) это библиотека не оринтирована на платформу ReactNative сугубо браузерное или Node.js использование. Собственно так как специфика и окруженение ReactNative другие мы не можем использововать в большинстве своем библиотеки для обычного реакта.